# Importing a DLL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllimport

I'm trying to import a dll to my C# project using DllImport as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key,string val,string filePath);
```

Also, I have added the namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Still, I'm getting an error:
"The name 'DllImport' does not exist in the current context"

Is there a limitation on where in a class you can import a dll?

Comment: Could you decribe where exactly in your class you placed your DLLImport statement?

Comment: I've tried placing it in the constructor of my class. Also tried placing it in some other function.

Comment: Well, thats the problem. Have a look at the updated answers now. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've probably also got the wrong return type in your statement. Try with **bool**:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern bool WritePrivateProfileString(string section, string key,string val,string filePath);
```

References: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725501(v=vs.85).aspx

**EDIT**:

DllImports have to be placed inside the body of your class. Not inside methods or the constructor.

```
public class Class1
{
     //DllImport goes here:
     [DllImport("kernel32")]
     private static extern ...

     public Class1()
     {
          ...
     }

     /* snip */
}
```

Comment: Changed that. Still not working. Its not recognizing DllImport at all. The function line would be executed after it recognizes it i guess.

Answer (score 2):

In your solution explorer, right-click references, select Add Reference, and add the System.Runtime.InteropServices to your project.

You can't do `using <assembly>;` if it's not also referenced in your project.

**EDIT**

Actually, just saw your comment on your question.  I think (haven't done Interop in a while) that it has to be outside a function, in the body of the class.

i.e.:

```
public class MyClass
{

    [DLLImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string sectio, string key, string val, string filePath);

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public void foo()
    {
    }

    // etc, etc
}
```

Comment: I'm doing using <namespace>; The assembly need for this is mscorlib.dll which AFAIK, is referenced automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding these parameters

```
[DllImport("kernel32",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

Comment: Still not working. Its not recognizing DllImport at all. The parameters would come after it recognizes it i guess.

Answer (score -1):

usually when importing win dll you use unsafe code sow be sure to check the project settings here are two simple tutorial that shows the code

[code for Kenler32.dll inport](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0520__Windows/DllImportloaddlllibrary.htm)

[MSDN whit explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)